# Power BI DirectQuery data won't load

Tags: azure, powerbi

I want to DirectQuery data from SQL database on the cloud into Power BI and visualise as a time series but I guess the data size is too large and it won't show. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Power BI will not load your whole database - it will send queries and aggregated data will be sent over the wire, thus the size of the data doesn't matter (at least not directly).

Comment: Hi @AndreyNikolov thanks for the reply, then is there a reason why the data won't show in a plot?

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: Hi @MurrayFoxcroft, there was no error, but the visualisation tile is blank..

Comment: Did you specify an x and y axis for the report - you need both for some reports before it renders. Did you try a table visual? Are you sure there is data coming from your query? A loading / slow visual should have a spinner on it so you can see it is waiting for the data.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft It seems like I did. I made sure there was data in the table and I could see it spinning.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft I'll have a try again later, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Added some options to consider as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "Transform data". Select your target table and click on the table icon. Use "Keep Top Rows" and configure a small number of rows (say 5).

[image]

Go back and see if your visual loads. If this succeeds you should consider:

1. See if you can trim you data set size using filters in PowerQuery / Transform Data (e.g. limiting date ranges).
2. Building pre-aggregated queries (or views) to provide less network traffic and load on PowerBI
3. Upping your Azure SQL tier (DTU / cores) to provide more database power
4. Manually adjusting the SQL timeout

[image]

If limiting to the top few rows does not work.

1. Check you can access the SQL DB from the desktop using Azure Data Explorer or SQL
2. Try a new PowerBI PBIX / file and do the simplest of queries and visuals to test if your PowerBI file is corrupt.
3. Check your database credentials are correct

[image]